# Blue color is not applying on drawable in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on drawable icons for app icons.I apply different color on icon dynamically which apply successfully on icons.but when i apply blue color either its dark blue or light blue, It does not appear on icon. can anybody tell the reason please. I am using this code to apply color.

```html
 colorCode = sp.getString("initialColor", "#ffffff");
        icon.setBounds(0, 0, sIconWidth, sIconHeight);
        int color = Color.parseColor(colorCode);
        int i = Color.argb(0,
                color, color, color);
        icon.mutate().setColorFilter(i, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your error?
That's not the right way to set an background color of your icon.

You should do:

```
        android:background="@color/nameOfYourColor"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image_button"
```

If you wanna make a shape, you sould declare the shape at Drawable folder and set the background as the shape name.

Comment: actually i am trying to put a color layer on the top of image. not  in of bacground image

Comment: So you should do the same thing.
But instead that, you will create an ImageView with your background color.
And create an Drawable xml  object. with the first parameter your image and the second the color what you wanna  and the shape.

Or  you should try this code over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312680/how-to-set-combined-color-for-overlapped-area-of-two-different-color-objects

yellowCircle.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x88ffff00,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);